# Is there any way to authenticate users on ssh with mysql?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-16.04, pam

I believe that user management is critical in a professional environment, which is why I am seeking to find more about this question. I am looking to setup a MySQL database that will control ssh users on Ubuntu 16.04. I have not been able to find any documentation on this. Is this possible?

I've tried looking through ssh and manipulating it like I would with FTP, with no success.

Comment: You mean you want to put usernames and passwords in the database, instead of files like `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow`?

Comment: You should look for a PAM module that uses MySQL. Unfortunately, when I google `pam mysql`, all I find is the other way -- using PAM to authenticate MySQL users.

Comment: I mean exactly using the usernames and the password through the database. Sadly, I am starting to push to think this is not possible.

Comment: If you want to centralize user management, this is usually done with a standard service like Active Directory.

Comment: This is the purpose of AD and LDAP, you should use one of the two.